# SQL not exists returning query values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having some trouble with a query to check differences between 2 identical tables with different rows.
This is the query

```
SELECT *
FROM [PROD01].[myDefDB].[forward].[fv] as DB01
WHERE TargetDate = '20150429' and
NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
    FROM [PROD02].[myDefDB].[forward].[fv] as DB02
    WHERE DB02.TargetDate = '20150429' and
        DB02.Id_Fw = DB01.Id_Fw and
        DB02.Id_Bl = DB01.Id_Bl and
        DB02.Id_Pt = DB01.Id_Pt and
        DB02.TargetDate = DB01.TargetDate and
        DB02.StartDate = DB01.EndDate and
        DB02.EndDate = DB01.EndDate and
        DB02.[Version] = DB01.[Version]
)
```

Consider that `[PROD02].[myDefDB].[forward].[fv]` is a subset of `[PROD01].[myDefDB].[forward].[fv]`, that performing a `SELECT count(*)` on both tables for the `TargetDate = '20150429'` returns me 2367 and 4103, so I expect to get 1736 from that query but I get more than 2000.

I considered all PKs in the `WHERE` clause. What am I missing?

Comment: Do any of your columns have NULL values in them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `EXCEPT` like this.

```
SELECT Id_Fw,Id_Bland,Id_Pt,TargetDate,StartDate,EndDate,[Version]
FROM [PROD01].[myDefDB].[forward].[fv] as DB01
WHERE TargetDate = '20150429'
EXCEPT
SELECT Id_Fw,Id_Bl,Id_Pt,TargetDate,StartDate,EndDate,[Version]
FROM [PROD02].[myDefDB].[forward].[fv] as DB02
WHERE TargetDate = '20150429'
```

This will get you all the rows in `PROD01` which are not in `PROD02`

Comment: You may want to correct the column name in first part **Id_Bland**

Comment: yeah thanks, it looks to be a typo from OP as well since both tables look to be same table in different instances

Comment: this code works, thank you! But what is wrong in the code I posted above? I have also a few tables where numerical values in a non index column are slightly different, so I cannot use `EXCEPT`

Comment: ok well, just found why... `DB02.StartDate = DB01.EndDate` instead of `DB02.StartDate = DB01.StartDate`